# Does docker (-compose) support pure L1 or L2 networking?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

As a hobby project I'm trying to build a "mini internet" from the ground up, including hosts, routers, dhcp, dns, tls, the works, but I'm having trouble finding a platform that is as "bare metal" as I need.

Docker compose looks like a great because of how easy and quick it is to spin up a container. However, when you network containers together, it seems to act like a switch, router, dhcp server, and potentially a dns server as well.

Is there any way to make docker (and compose) link two containers together as if they have a direct hard wire ethernet connection between them? Or at the very least, a basic pure L2 switch?

Or if not, do you have any other recommendations for platforms that support this kind of nonsense?

Comment: When connecting multiple docker containers to the same network using the (default) bridge driver, they can directly communicate with each other. Docker asks iptables by default for forwarding network traffic to the internet. You will almost have a standalone network if you negate these rules for this specific network (or remove them altogether if you don´t want any forwarding). You can override the DNS server that is in use as well; see https://docs.docker.com/network/. However, perhaps a better solution for your hobby project would be to experiment with a hypervisor (e.g. Xen).

Comment: @rrr Thanks for the tips! I might go that route of just telling the containers to route differently. I'm wanting to use docker compose specifically due to the ease of spinning up entire networks easily. Maybe a lightweight vm could do the trick like you suggested. I'm also looking into this plugin. https://github.com/KatharaFramework/NetworkPlugin I'll answer my own question if i can get it to work the way i want